# Shower without a door and something that could serve as a door and restraint waters

Tags: bathroom, shower, bathroom-fixtures

In a shower that is open i.e. it has a glass panel on the side but no door, is there something sold that helps restraining the waters during the shower i.e. mimic a small door?

Comment: A shower curtain?

Comment: @SolarMike: I am not sure it is possible because the one side is the glass panel and the other side is a tile wall. So I don't think it is possible to support it

Comment: A photo would help. The shower rod could be to the side or adjacent to the glass wall. With out seeing the space it is just a guessing game.

Comment: @AlaskaMan: It is like this except for the big shower that is vertical https://s3-production.bobvila.com/articles/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Doorless_Shower_Tall.jpg

Answer (score 1):

U can actually get a specialty shower rod or even a regular shower rod and put you up a shower curtain they make shower curtains that are for walk in showers they also make plastic accordion doors that can be used and they can actually work well and relatively cheap

Comment: Do you have an example I can check? E.g something in amazon or any other store?

Comment: Does this mean that they have to be attached on the side?